# YouTube analytics API missing data for last 3 Days

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

We are calling the [metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics) endpoint to retrieve likes, dislikes, comments, shares and avg watch time for specific

```
https://www.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel==MINE&dimensions=video&metrics=likes,dislikes,comments,shares,averageViewDuration&startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}&filters=video==${video_id}
```

Which works and correctly returns data - however the data for the last 3 days is always empty rows. See the below screenshot with the dates and the empty row property

[image]

The value for the 14th of November is correct - but when we fetch for the 15th, 16th or 17th we get empty rows. We have tested this all week and it is always the last 3 days. Tomorrow we will have valid data for the 15th but not the 16th, 17th or 18th.

We also know there is valid data for these dates - see the image below for the values on YouTube analytics

The dip in the graph is the 14th at 3 likes. But we should have 4 for the 15th and 1 for the 16th.

[image]

Any ideas how we retrieve the correct data for the last 3 days?

Comment: This is data latency.  The data hasn't completed processing yet.

Comment: for 72 hours? We lose a full three days of data from their api endpoints, this isn't the issue with other google apis. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: YouTube analytics only stores data for three months.    its a free system you get what you pay for.

Comment: They need time to process the data don't bother trying to request Data that is less than 72 hours old

Comment: Yes, you can't get the data form the last 3 days, but testing the API, I was able to fetch the daily likes down to 2013 when the channel was created :D